# C# - Algoritmos - For loop - Lógica - Usar valor anterior de uma variável e valor atual de uma outra variável

Tags: c#, algoritmo, for, lógica

## [DOTNET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J6Emu6)

## Edição

Os cálculos abaixo correspondem a variáveis de cálculo atuarial. As idades de "idade atual" até a idade de 120 anos percorrem as probabilidades de morte de uma pessoa usando uma tábua chamada RP-2000.

O segundo loop que vai de 0 a 22 corresponde a idades de entrada em aposentadoria, para cálculo de elegibilidade aos benefícios do plano, o que também leva em consideração as idades do parágrafo anterior para cada beneficiário ou participante do plano.

Não acho necessário publicar os cálculos completos para o problema, porque seria muito complicado entender tudo.

---

## Original

No código abaixo, as variáveis `sampleVar` e `dummyVar` são calculadas pelo *loop* interno. Na classe `Program` existem três métodos: o método `Program.Qx()` retorna o valor de `qx`, que é um valor pre-definido. O método `Program.SampleVar()` calcula o valor de `sampleVar`; e o método `Program.DummyVar()` calcula o valor de `dummyVar`.

A ideia aqui é "envelhecer" uma pessoa, digamos. Essa pessoa tem um idade atual e temos que percorrer cada valor de `Program.Qx()`, que vai de 0 até 120 anos, da idade atual da pessoa até 120 anos, que é a última idade de `Program.Qx()`.

Meu problema aqui é calcular o valor correto de `dummyVar`.

`dummyVar` sempre começa com 1 na primeira iteração; depois usa seu valor anterior e o valor atual de `sampleVar` para o cálculo dos seus demais valores, isto é, `dummyVar` faz referência ao seu próprio valor anterior.

Abaixo está o código:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        // A idade é calculada para várias pessoas e vem do banco de dados
        // A idade abaixo serve para essa demonstração
        int idade = 25;
        
        // "Envelhece" a pessoa da idade atual até a idade de 120 anos
        for (int i = idade; i <= 120; i++) {
            double qx = p.Qx(i - 1);
            double sampleVar;
            double dummyVar = 1;
            
            // Para cada idade, da idade atual até a idade de 120 anos, calcula os valores de 
            // sampleVar e dummyVar e depois escreve a saída no Console
            for (int j = 0; j <= 22; j++) {
                sampleVar = p.SampleVar(qx);
                
                Console.WriteLine("Idade: " + i + " - Sample var: " + sampleVar + " - Dummy Var: " + dummyVar);
                
                // Atualiza o valor de dummyVar
                dummyVar = p.DummyVar(sampleVar, dummyVar);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    // Representa a conjunção de Program.SampleVar() e Program.DummyVar()
    public double DummyVar(double sampleVar, double dummyVar)
    {
        return dummyVar *= sampleVar;
    }
    
    // Representa a probabilidade complementar de Program.Qx()
    // Program.SampleVar() é calculada a partir da idade atual da pessoa
    public double SampleVar(double qx)
    {
        return 1 - qx;
    }

    // Representa uma probabilidade para as idade de 0 até 120 anos
    public double Qx(int idade)
    {
        double[] rpm = new double[] {
                0.000000,
                0.000510,
                0.000344,
                0.000286,
                0.000222,
                0.000204,
                0.000195,
                0.000187,
                0.000173,
                0.000167,
                0.000170,
                0.000175,
                0.000182,
                0.000192,
                0.000203,
                0.000215,
                0.000227,
                0.000241,
                0.000253,
                0.000265,
                0.000276,
                0.000286,
                0.000293,
                0.000298,
                0.000300,
                0.000301,
                0.000302,
                0.000306,
                0.000314,
                0.000330,
                0.000355,
                0.000399,
                0.000450,
                0.000505,
                0.000562,
                0.000618,
                0.000673,
                0.000723,
                0.000771,
                0.000817,
                0.000863,
                0.000914,
                0.000972,
                0.001039,
                0.001118,
                0.001206,
                0.001293,
                0.001387,
                0.001488,
                0.001596,
                0.001710,
                0.001959,
                0.002134,
                0.002333,
                0.002557,
                0.002899,
                0.003360,
                0.003754,
                0.004218,
                0.004756,
                0.005398,
                0.006141,
                0.007006,
                0.008010,
                0.009024,
                0.010190,
                0.011527,
                0.012860,
                0.014297,
                0.015842,
                0.017765,
                0.019656,
                0.021825,
                0.024310,
                0.027120,
                0.030267,
                0.033735,
                0.037525,
                0.041698,
                0.046342,
                0.051494,
                0.057633,
                0.064389,
                0.071774,
                0.079823,
                0.088606,
                0.098238,
                0.108834,
                0.120472,
                0.133136,
                0.146726,
                0.159815,
                0.173284,
                0.186930,
                0.200554,
                0.213993,
                0.227124,
                0.239882,
                0.252237,
                0.264166,
                0.275645,
                0.286902,
                0.297348,
                0.306432,
                0.313602,
                0.318309,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                1.000000
        };

        if (idade < rpm.Length)
        {
            return rpm[idade];
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

A saída d código acima é a seguinte para as duas primeiras idades:

```
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.9997
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.99940009
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.999100269973
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.998800539892008
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.998500899730041
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.998201349460122
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.997901889055284
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.997602518488567
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.997303237733021
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.997004046761701
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.996704945547672
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.996405934064008
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.996107012283789
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.995808180180104
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.99550943772605
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.995210784894732
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.994912221659263
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.994613747992766
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.994315363868368
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.994017069259207
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.99371886413843
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 0.993420748479188
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999398090601
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999097271775729
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.998796543496925
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.998495905737332
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.998195358469705
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.997894901666806
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.997594535301404
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.997294259346278
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.996994073774215
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.996693978558009
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.996393973670463
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.996094059084388
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.995794234772604
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.995494500707937
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.995194856863224
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.994895303211309
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.994595839725042
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.994296466377285
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.993997183140905
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.99369798998878
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.993398886893793
```

Visualmente o cálculo se faz da seguinte forma:

```
      dummyVar               sampleVar                  Idade
+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|          1              |        0.9997         |      25     |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|     1 * 0.999699        |        0.999699       |      26     |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| 0.999699 * 0.999698     |        0.999698       |      27     |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| 0.9993970909 * 0.999694 |        0.999694       |      28     |
+-------------------------|-----------------------+-------------+
```

Percebam que o valor de `sampleVar` para a idade de 25 anos nunca é usado, ou seja, o primeiro valor de `sampleVar` não tem dependentes.

Como isso acontece no segundo loop, o resultado esperado seria o seguinte:

```
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 25 - Sample var: 0.9997 - Dummy Var: 1
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 26 - Sample var: 0.999699 - Dummy Var: 0.999699
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
Idade: 27 - Sample var: 0.999698 - Dummy Var: 0.9993970909
```

**Qual seria a forma correta de implementar a lógica para conseguir a saída acima?**

Estou à disposição para dirimir dúvidas em relação ao problema.

Comment: Com certeza você ofuscou o nome das variáveis, é super péssimo tentar entender isso, você poderia publicar o que significa cada variável?

Comment: Eu adicionei mais informação no topo, Edney. Obrigado!

Comment: O código que eu postei resolveu? E por que tem 2 loops? se os valores são os mesmos?

Comment: O primeiro loop é pra "envelhecer" a pessoa, o segundo loop é para calcular a elegibilidade de acordo com 23 idades de entrada em aposentadoria distintas para cada idade de "envelhecimento" da pessoa. Ainda não resolveu o problema, mas eu dei +1 por conta do uso de dicionários.

Comment: O que ficou errado? por que a saída ficou identica, exceto por erros de arredondamento...

Comment: Ainda estou testando, só isso. Daqui a pouco informo direitinho o que aconteceu.

Comment: Beleza, desculpe se te pressionei, se por acaso não conseguir mesmo assim, posta um excel com os calculos certinhos, pra ter uma idéia de qual é o cálculo exato.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei por que você utilizou dois loops aninhados, se os valores esperados são os mesmos.

Se não for isso o esperado, posta um comentário.

Fatorei um pouco seu código:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DummyVar
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static double[] rpm = new double[] {
                0.000000,
                0.000510,
                0.000344,
                0.000286,
                0.000222,
                0.000204,
                0.000195,
                0.000187,
                0.000173,
                0.000167,
                0.000170,
                0.000175,
                0.000182,
                0.000192,
                0.000203,
                0.000215,
                0.000227,
                0.000241,
                0.000253,
                0.000265,
                0.000276,
                0.000286,
                0.000293,
                0.000298,
                0.000300,
                0.000301,
                0.000302,
                0.000306,
                0.000314,
                0.000330,
                0.000355,
                0.000399,
                0.000450,
                0.000505,
                0.000562,
                0.000618,
                0.000673,
                0.000723,
                0.000771,
                0.000817,
                0.000863,
                0.000914,
                0.000972,
                0.001039,
                0.001118,
                0.001206,
                0.001293,
                0.001387,
                0.001488,
                0.001596,
                0.001710,
                0.001959,
                0.002134,
                0.002333,
                0.002557,
                0.002899,
                0.003360,
                0.003754,
                0.004218,
                0.004756,
                0.005398,
                0.006141,
                0.007006,
                0.008010,
                0.009024,
                0.010190,
                0.011527,
                0.012860,
                0.014297,
                0.015842,
                0.017765,
                0.019656,
                0.021825,
                0.024310,
                0.027120,
                0.030267,
                0.033735,
                0.037525,
                0.041698,
                0.046342,
                0.051494,
                0.057633,
                0.064389,
                0.071774,
                0.079823,
                0.088606,
                0.098238,
                0.108834,
                0.120472,
                0.133136,
                0.146726,
                0.159815,
                0.173284,
                0.186930,
                0.200554,
                0.213993,
                0.227124,
                0.239882,
                0.252237,
                0.264166,
                0.275645,
                0.286902,
                0.297348,
                0.306432,
                0.313602,
                0.318309,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                0.320000,
                1.000000
        };

        public static void Main()
        {
            Dictionary<int, double> dummyVar = new Dictionary<int, double>();
            Dictionary<int, double> sampleVar = new Dictionary<int, double>();

            var idade = 25;

            dummyVar.Add(idade, 1);
            sampleVar.Add(idade, 1 - rpm[idade-1]);

            for (int i = 26; i <= 120; i++)
            {
                dummyVar.Add(i, dummyVar[i-1]* sampleVar[i - 1]);
                sampleVar.Add(i, 1 - rpm[i - 1]);
            }

            for (int i = 25; i <= 120; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 22; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Idade: " + i + " - Sample var: " + sampleVar[i] + " - Dummy Var: " + dummyVar[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```